# Apache2 forward logs to rsyslog AND locally

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, syslog

Right now I'm storing apache2 logs locally:

```
ErrorLog     /var/log/apache2/one.error.log
CustomLog    /var/log/apache2/one.access.log common
```

How can I keep storing the logs locally but also forward them to a local rsyslog (who is pushing data to a remote rsyslog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple access logs can be created simply by specifying multiple `CustomLog` directives in the configuration file.

See also piped logs for alternatives with syslog, Apache allows you to pipe logs straight to the `stdin` of a process:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped